# Maven plugin: Passing all available properties to an Interpolator

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

In a Maven plugin I would like to use all properties usually available to the pom inside an Interpolator through a ValueSource.

I can access properties defined inside the pom, system properties and environment variable properties using one of MavenProject#getProperties(), MavenSession#getProperties() or MavenProject#getModel()#getProperties. This works fine with code like that:

```
import org.codehaus.plexus.interpolation.PropertiesBasedValueSource;

ValueSource valueSource = new PropertiesBasedValueSource( project.getModel()
                   .getProperties() )
```

However, the standard project properties like `project.version` or `project.build.directory` are not part of any of those Properties instances. How can I get all of them at once in a properties instance?

My plugin runs in the generate-sources phase using Maven 2.2.1 or 3.0.3.

Comment: I would define a parameter in my plugin with a default value like *${project.version}* which will be handled by the plexus container.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to my own question :-):

I want to pass all properties available normally in filters. While I could set each and every property available as a parameter to my plugin, that solution would require to modify the plugin source code and recompile it whenever new properties get added tomaven. Also, the source code of the mojo would grow to a high number of lines.

The `project.*` properties are not actually properties available through the `Project#getProperties` method when used in filters. Instead they are mapped directly to the getter methods of the project object itself. The class doing that is `PrefixedObjectValueSource` in the same interpolation package as `PropertiesBasedValueSource`. It will map each getter method (bean property) to a property, prefixing it with a defined string, and recursively exposing the bean properties of each property.

```
  import org.codehaus.plexus.interpolation.PrefixedObjectValueSource;
  import org.codehaus.plexus.interpolation.PropertiesBasedValueSource;

  ValueSource allProperties = new PropertiesBasedValueSource( getProject().getModel()
                   .getProperties() );
  ValueSource projectProperties =
              new PrefixedObjectValueSource( "project.", getProject() ) );
```